# replacing text in multiple text files using VBS

Tags: file, text, replace, vbscript

Im trying to write a VBS script that will cycle through multiple text files and replace several keywords with other words e.g. replace 1ECODE with GJA. 
I have working code that will do this for a single file which is detailed in the code but cant make it cycle through several text files.

my current code (which is from another thread) is below which returns the error "Object doesnt support this property or method 'f.FullName'

The files to edit are all called "testfile_1.txt", "testfile_2.txt" etc etc

any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set prefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
prefixes.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'make dictionary lookups case-insensitive
prefixes.Add "testfile", True


For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\msi\Documents\script_test\Test_folder").Files
  If InStr(f.Name, "_") > 0 Then
    If prefixes.Exists(Split(f.Name, "_")(0)) Then
      strText = fso.OpenTextFile(f.FullName).ReadAll

      strText = Replace(strText, "1ECODE", "ELH")
      strText = Replace(strText, "1GCODE", "GLH")
      strText = Replace(strText, "2ECODE", "EQT")
      strText = Replace(strText, "2GCODE", "GQT")
      strText = Replace(strText, "3ECODE", "EQT")
      strText = Replace(strText, "3GCODE", "GQT")


 fso.OpenTextFile(f.FullName, 2).Write strText
    End If
     End IF
 Next
```

Comment: What are you using really `VBA` or `VBS`? `VBA` is different which will be associated with another app such as Excel, Word etc and `VBS` can be run as standalone.

Comment: using VBS as I need it to run as standalone

Answer (score 1):

`File` object does not have `FullName` property, use `Path` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Matt you need to use `f.Path` wherever you have used `f.FullName`.

Comment: as @shrivallabha.redij said

Comment: sorry, my knowledge isnt that good, could you be more specific please?

Comment: on which line? Is the path proper?

Comment: so the path `"C:\Users\msi\Documents\script_test\Test_folder"` is not proper obviously

Comment: thanks for the help, but I appear to have solved it myself

Answer (score -1):

changed the code to this and it appears to be working as required.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each f In       fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\ms\\Documents\Temporary_delete_every_month\script_test\Test_folder").Files

  msgbox f

set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(f,ForReading)
StrText= objFile.ReadAll
ObjFile.close
Set objFile= nothing

strText = Replace(strText, "1ECODE", "YYY")
strText = Replace(strText, "2ECODE", "XXX")

set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(f,ForWriting)

objFile.WriteLine strText

 objFile.Close

 Next
```